# Can call login command from terminal

Tags: bash, centos, terminal, gnome, login

I want to create a user using `useradd` from root in my terminal window, after it I call `passwd` to set user's password.

1. So I cant call `login username` because when I call it from terminal it closes terminal's window.
2. I can write `login` and then write user's name but this does not work because it says that `Login incorrect`.
3. I can call `su user` to login as new user. This command will allow me to work with new user.
4. I can login to my new user from graphical login window (startup login window)
5. If I write from terminal `init 3`, then I can write my user's name and password and login
6. I can login as new user if my OS is running in non graphical mode.

I tested it in CentOS 5.5,6.5. I want to login as new user using **login** command from terminal when my OS is running in grephical mode. How can I do it?

**SOLUTION**:
Someone adviced me to call `su -l user`

Comment: It seems to me you already listed the answer to your question as #3 in your list: "I can call su user to login as new user. This command will allow me to work with new user."

Comment: I want to login as new user using `login(not su)` command from terminal when my OS is running in grephical mode. This thing I need for my administrative needs.

Comment: You don't want to use `su` yet that's exactly what `su` is for. You could use `login` as well, I suppose. I don't know what you mean by "halts my terminal" because I am able to run `login` from a terminal and it works just fine.

Comment: What OS do you use? "halts my terminal" - closes terminal window

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. You can't have two users logged in to the GUI simultaneously. If you want to stay logged in to the GUI (yourself) and also login as the new user, and you have a problem with `login`, and you don't like `su`, then how about `telnet`ing or `ssh`ing to `localhost` and logging in (as the new user) that way?

Comment: Why do you need to login as the user? You can set their password with `useradd`, or you can use `passwd username` to set their password after adding the account.

Comment: The `login` command works only in certain circumstances. Running in a pty opened by the window system is unfortunately not one of those circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you just want to change the user's password. In which case you can (as root) type:

```
passwd user-name
```